# OpenProcess call returns pseudo handle

Tags: winapi, openprocess

MSDN says that [`OpenProcess()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684320.aspx) must return either a valid handle, or NULL on error.

However, I met a rare situation on Win7 x64 (and also on Win 8.1 x86, Win XP x64, Win Vista x64) where `OpenProcess()` returned -1 for the current process, i.e. the pseudo handle, while I enumerated processes. It occurs very rarely from time to time (when I run my test suite on different platforms). And I can't reproduce it on Win 10.

Then `CloseHandle()` fails on this handle with `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE` error. But on the other hand MSDN says that

> The pseudo handle need not be closed when it is no longer needed.
>   Calling the CloseHandle function with a pseudo handle has no effect.

Why does this happen? Is it correct behavior for `OpenProcess()`?

Below is an example of my code:

```
HANDLE snap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot (TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
PROCESSENTRY32 prEntry = {};
prEntry.dwSize = sizeof (PROCESSENTRY32);
if (Process32First (snap, &prEntry))
{
   do
   {
       if (prEntry.th32ProcessID)
       {
           HANDLE h = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, prEntry.th32ProcessID);
           // <<<< from time to time h is (-1) here when meets the current process
           if (h)
           {
               wchar_t imageFilename[MAX_PATH + 1] = {};
               if (GetProcessImageFileName(hProc, imageFilename, MAX_PATH))
               {
                   // do something
               }
               if (!CloseHandle(h))
               {
                   // CLoseHandle returns FALSE on pseudo handle (at least on Win 7)
                   DWORD err = ::GetLastError();
                   // err == 0x6, i.e. ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE, for the pseudo handle
                   // << create a memory dump here for further analysis
               }
           }
       }
   }
   while (Process32Next (snap, &prEntry));
}
```

UPD: I found why my tests never fail on Win 10 platform - `CloseHandle(HANDLE(-1))` always returns `TRUE` on Win 10, while on Win 7 it returns `FALSE` with 0x6 error. But I still have no explanation about `OpenProcess()` behaviour.

SOLUTION: As Ben Voigt said (see the accepted answer) there was a hook in the test environment, which was not cleared after the previous test suite run. After days of debugging the hook was found and localized, the test suite was fixed to clean the hooks up. Now OpenProcess call works correctly.

Comment: *It occurs very rare* - almost sure you mistake. `OpenProcess` hard-coded return 0 on error. if assume that on some version `kernelbase.dll` hardcode to `-1` - it will be not rare but always. simply pass say invalid process id to `OpenProcess` - which value you get ?

Comment: OpenProcess returns NULL on error as MSDN says. The questions is why does OpenProcess return HANDLE(-1)?
(OK, it's not an invalid handle, but the question is still not answered.)

Comment: so look why it return -1 (if really) return. go to asm code. look from where. what return your OpenProcess on invalid id for example ?

Comment: Working on it now. Unfortunately in my case I've got only memory dumps on my tests fail when CloseHandle returns FALSE. Maybe my problem is not the HANDLE(-1).

Comment: at first direct call `OpenProcess` from some test code. then - why memory dumps - in what problem debug code ? however i absolute sure that you mistake. you never got -1

Comment: Can you call `HANDLE h = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, GetCurrentProcessId());` and post result here?

Comment: hProc = 0x00000100

Comment: I updated the question. OpenProcess returns -1 on the current process (from time to time). Then CloseHandle fails on the handle.

Comment: Still strange why you get this result only "from time to time". Symptoms like that are common when you have uninitialized variables or race conditions of threads. A [mcve] with proper error checking would be helpful.

Comment: *Then CloseHandle fails on the handle* - `CloseHandle` not fail on -1;

Comment: @RbMm You're wrong, it does. `CloseHandle(HANDLE(-1))` or `CloseHandle(GetCurrentProcess())` returns `FALSE` on Win 7 with VS2017, `GetLastError` returns 0x6 right after this.

Comment: yes, just check, on win7 `CloseHandle(HANDLE(-1))` really return error invalid handle. but how here VS2017 related ??

Comment: Of course `CloseHandle(-1)` must cause error "invalid handle" because this is the constant `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`.  `OpenProcess` shouldn't return that, but many other kernel handle functions do, and `CloseHandle` treats it accordingly.

Comment: @RbMm I mentioned VS2017 to specify my environment.

Comment: related: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040302-00/?p=40443

Comment: result of win api can can not depend from vs version or at vs at all

Comment: Also, `-1` from `OpenProcess` is not a pseudo-handle, it's a failure.  [`GetCurrentProcess` docs say "A process can create a "real" handle to itself that is valid in the context of other processes, or that can be inherited by other processes, by specifying the pseudo handle as the source handle in a call to the DuplicateHandle function. **A process can also use the OpenProcess function to open a real handle to itself.**"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683179.aspx)

Comment: @BenVoigt However  `CloseHandle(-1)` on Win 10 returns `TRUE`. And of course, I expect that `OpenProcess` should return a valid handle, not a pseudo handle. The point is my tests fail from time to time on different platforms due to `OpenProcess` returns (-1) for unknown reasons. Please see my question above for details.

Comment: @Rom098: Well, what does `GetLastError` return when you get the `-1`?  `GetLastError` immediately after `OpenProcess`, that is, not after `CloseHandle`

Comment: @BenVoigt I need to check this on Monday. On the other hand `-1` doesn't indicate an error. `OpenProcess` returns `NULL` when fails.

Comment: @Rom098: `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` *does* indicate an error.  `OpenProcess` isn't supposed to use it.

Comment: @BenVoigt [_A pseudo handle is a special constant, currently (HANDLE)-1, that is interpreted as the current process handle._](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683179(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @Rom098: `OpenProcess` never returns a pseudo handle.  See my answer for possible explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely explanation is a poorly written `OpenProcess` hook, for example both antimalware and malware use such hooks.

Writer of this hook didn't read the `OpenProcess` documentation carefully, and when real Windows `OpenProcess` succeeds but the hook wants to block your access, it is doing

```
return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
```

(This could be a copy/paste error from also writing a `CreateFile` hook)

Due to the fact such hooks are predominantly used in rootkits -- both "evil" and ["good" (but accidentally evil anyway)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sony_BMG_copy_protection_rootkit_scandal) varieties, you probably won't be able to confirm the hook from inside the system.  A kernel debugger connection, on the other hand, should show that during real Windows OpenProcess execution, the return address is to the hook code, not the kernel transition stub.

Comment: How can I know is there any hook on WinAPI function, e.g. OpenProcess?

Comment: Really, it was a hook.